# FFMPEG Image to video zoompan starting position

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

In creating mp4 slideshows out of images, I've taken some examples online for zoompan, but I still haven't quite grasped how to make them start from a certain location in an image. Here's the typical command:

ffmpeg -i image-000.jpg -filter_complex "color=c=black:r=60:s=1920x1080[demo];[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.2)':s=2000x1333:d=360:x='if(gte(zoom,0.9),x,x+1/a)':y='if(gte(zoom,0.9),y,y+1)',fade=in:0:25:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0.0/TB[v0];[demo][v0]overlay=format=yuv420"
-t 6 -c:v libx264 -y out000.mp4

Photos I use are typically 3x2 or 4x3 in aspect ratio, so I get that they'd have to be cut off somewhere in a 16x9 video. The thing with the above code (and many other "Ken Burns effect" samples) is that they start with the bottom portion of the images cut off, then either zoom in more or zoom out, never showing the bottom.

**How do I get the animation to start further down on the image?** Nothing I do in the y='...' section affects it. Not even putting in constant numbers between 0 and 100000 instead of adjusting values in that formula *y='if(gte(zoom,0.9),y,y+1)'*.

Note: I've had some success using *crop* or *pad* for the original image, but I'd rather understand how to better position zoompan inside of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since zoom can never be less than 1, in the expr `'if(gte(zoom,0.9),x,x+1/a)`, `gte(zoom,0.9)` will always be true and the expr will always evaluate to `x`. x is initialized as 0, so the expr will always evaluate to 0. Same for the y expr.

Use

`y='if(on,y-1,ih-ih/zoom)`

to start anim from the bottom and going up. `on` is output frame count and starts from zero, so first frame is set at bottom, and then each frame moves 1 pixel up.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick for the different pans I'm playing with. It also makes rendering a bit faster now that I don't need to crop and pad ahead of the scaling to get similar results.